# getting two errors here

Tags: asp.net, global, freetextbox

firstly i am getting the error-
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.Global'.

Source Error:

Line 1: `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" Language="C#" %>`

Source File: /global.asax Line: 1

secondly i am getting the error-
Error 1 Unable to resolve type `'FreeTextBoxControls.FreeTextBox, FreeTextBox, Version=3.3.1.12354, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5962a4e684a48b87'`
in the file licenses.licx when i have downloaded a richtextcontrol(freetextboxcontrol) and placed on the page
.. i need suggestions

Answer (score 2):

For first part, it could not find the file Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" which your .aspx file is inheriting, so remove this attribute from Page

for second part went to 'Project' --> 'Add Reference...' selected the 'Browse' tab, browsed to the Bin folder and added a 'FreeTextBox.dll' reference.

it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on Project
2. Choose Add Reference.
3. Selected the 'Browse' tab
4. Browsed to the Bin folder or where located this dll 'FreeTextBox.dll' and added a 'FreeTextBox.dll'